# How to include the jars referenced in "Java Build Path" section of an Eclipse project in a jar file generated with Ant using a build.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ant

basically that's my requirement , if someone adds or deletes a jar reference in the section "Java Build Path" , then that jar should be included ( or not included in case of deletion)  when the project is built and a jar of the project is generated with a build.xml ant file. I was expecting to reference a property or variable in the xml file. something like:

```
<!-- copy the JARs that you need to "target" directory  -->
<copy todir="target">
    <fileset dir="${buildPath}" includes="*.jar" />
</copy>
```

where ${buildPath} is pointing to "Java Build Path". That is just an example and doesn't work

Notice that I don't want to put every jar individually  in the build.xml , but to use something like includes="*.jar" , so if someone changes "Java Build Path" , I don't have to change the build.xml

Comment: "Java build Path" is not a directory. It's a classpath container (i.e. an eclipse abstraction containing pointers to multiple libraries. Take a look at the file ".classpath" and you will see the "Java Build Path")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the Eclipse build path and class path from an Ant build file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404224/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-build-path-and-class-path-from-an-ant-build-file)

Comment: @Lucas , I don't have that option , thanks anyway

Comment: @ben75 , so is there a way to reference that classpath container from my build.xml file ?

Comment: @Lucas it is not the same question , that refers to having a lib folder in the project and use that as the jars directory, I am asking a reference to "Java build Path", that  pointed out by ben75 above, it is not a directory.

Comment: @Leo, the question is not exactly the same, but the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2404280/516433) should help you.  I added a brief description below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Java Build Path* in eclipse is actually backed by the `.classpath` file in your eclipse project.  So if you look in that file you will see all of the paths used by eclipse.  You can parse them out of there with ant.  For example, I have a simple project that has a *Java Build Path* that points the the standard JRE libraries and a link to a jar from another project (dataset-tools).  This is my `.classpath`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/dataset-tools/target/dataset-tools.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

So, as you can see, if you add a new jar to your *Java Build Path* it is reflected in the `.classpath` file thusly:

```
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/dataset-tools/target/dataset-tools.jar"/>
```

You could use ant to parse that file looking for these `classpathentry` elements with kind `lib`.  This is the same answer presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404224/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-build-path-and-class-path-from-an-ant-build-file).

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse build path information is stored in the `.classpath` file, and you can probably parse out the simple bits from this (entries that point to single JAR files either within the project workspace or externally with absolute paths) but this will only get you so far - there are other types of classpath entries such as those based on "classpath variables", references to other projects in the workspace, or other types of containers provided by Eclipse plugins.  For example, I have the GGTS plugins (for Groovy and Grails) and my Grails project's `.classpath` has no explicitly listed JARs at all, it simply says

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
```

There is an [Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) project which claims to help with this, but the most recent release ("milestone 4") is from mid-2010 and I've no idea how well it works with more recent Eclipses.

A better approach may be to manage your dependencies declaratively using [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), and have both the Ant build *and* the Eclipse project (using [IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/)) take their libraries from there.  When you want to add or remove a dependency you just edit the `ivy.xml` file and both Ant and Eclipse will pick up the change on their next build.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I cannot change the environment in this way (adding Ivy). I will consider that in future projects started by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the xmlproperty task to read the .classpath into property values.

```
<xmlproperty file=".classpath" collapseAttributes="true" delimiter=";" />
```

Then set that value in the path

```
<path id="eclipse.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${classpath.classpathentry.path}"/>
</path>


<target name="compile" depends="init">

    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" updatedProperty="compiled">
        <classpath refid="eclipse.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```